# How to transform values from one probability distribution to another

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, transformation

Suppose that I draw randomly the number $0.6$ from the $U \sim \text{Unif}(0, 1)$ distribution. I want to transform this so it follows the distribution of an $Y \sim \exp(\frac 1 2)$ random variable.

I know that we can write $Y = -2\ln(U)$, so does it suffices to just substitute $0.6$ for $U$ in that expression? Or is something more complicated needed?

Answer (score 1):

If $U=0.6$ and $Y=-2\ln(U)$ then indeed $Y=-2\ln(0.6)$ .